# Scrapy output only the last incrementally updated item

Tags: scrapy

Can someone help me with this please, I have been searching for this information for 2 days, no luck.

I have an item with 1 field as a list of another items. The spider works fine, but in the output file I get all the lines of this item.

For example, I need json to be printed as:

```
{"id": "AAAA", "details": [
{"date" : "2013-01-10", type="A"},
{"date" : "2013-02-10", type="B"},
{"date" : "2013-03-10", type="C"},
{"date" : "2013-04-10"}, type="D"]}
```

but I get:

```
{"id": "AAAA", "details": [
{"date" : "2013-01-10", type="A"}]}

{"id": "AAAA", "details": [
{"date" : "2013-01-10", type="A"},
{"date" : "2013-02-10", type="B"}]}

{"id": "AAAA", "details": [
{"date" : "2013-01-10", type="A"},
{"date" : "2013-02-10", type="B"},
{"date" : "2013-03-10", type="C"}
]}

{"id": "AAAA", "details": [
{"date" : "2013-01-10", type="A"},
{"date" : "2013-02-10", type="B"},
{"date" : "2013-03-10", type="C"},
{"date" : "2013-04-10"}, type="D"]}
```

I use a function to update my parent item:

```
def rePackIt(parent, item):
    if 'details' in parent:
        items = parent.get('details')
    else:
        items = []
    items.append(dict(item))
    parent['details'] = items

return parent
```

In parse function I do:

```
parent = ParentItem()
parent['id'] = self.param   # actually I parse a text file with many IDs
parent['details'] = []

yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                    formname='...',
                                    formdata={'...':'...', '...': parent['id'], 
                                              '...':''},
                                    meta = {'parent': parent, 'dont_merge_cookies': True},
                                    callback=self.parse1)


def parse1(self, response):
    parent = response.meta['parent']
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    records = sel.select('//ul[@class="...."]')
    for record in records:
        item = DetailItem()
        item['type'] = record.select('child...')
        doc_link = record.select('child.../a/@href').extract()
        yield Request(doc_link,
                              callback=self.parse2,
                              method='GET',
                              headers={...},
                              meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True, 'cookiejar': cookieJar, 'item'  : item, 'parent' : parent}
                          )
  def parse2(self, response):
      item = response.meta['item']
      parent = response.meta['parent']
      sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      # some other parsing code
      item['date'] = cell.select('span[1]/text()[1]').extact()
      rePackIt(parent, item)
      return parent
```

Comment: can you share some of your spider code? especially how you instantiate your item(s) and set this list of dates?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I was waiting for any notifications of reply in my gmail, but it didn't arrive. I will update the body of the question now.

Comment: Hi, Paul. Have you seen the code? I am still waiting for any comments from your side. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are trying to scrap and output as json has this structure

- MainItem 1 {some information }

  - Detail Item 1
  - Detail Item 2
- Main Item 2

  - Detail Item 1
  - Detail Item 2

You are returning the parent object for each of the detail item scrapped. While your intention is to return the parent object only once, after it is "complete". Meaning your parent is populated with all the detailed item 1..n. The problem is you don't have a nicer way to say when you finished building the parent item.

One of way to handle this would be writing the pipeline(http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html). This might sound complicated but its not.

Basically, there is three steps in the pipeline

**open_spider**

you create your global object of the form

itemlist = []

**process_item**

```
if item is parent then
   add the item to the list 
if item is child then
   find the parentitem from the itemlist
   parentitem["detail"].add(childitem)
```

**close_spider**

Write your json serialise and write to the desired file. One caveat with this is, if you are scrapping huge data, all the scraped item will live in memory, until you write them to the file in this method, as you won't be able to stream write your json items.

Let me know if this works or did you find any better solution.

Comment: thank you a lot for this solution. I am back to work and I will check it now, and get back. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi, I have tested this solution and it is working just perfect, thank you a lot!!! I tested it with several cases and my output JSON files are as they should be. Just one more thing: self.itemlist = [] I wrote inside _init_ method. Thank you again!!!

Comment: sorry,  I can't vote UP bcoz I am new here and I don't have enough points.

Comment: ooh, i missed that check mark... now it's done.  Have a nice day and week.